# Symbol for "defined to be logically equivalent" (:⇔)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

Is there a way to typeset the symbol ":⇔" **correctly** in LaTeX (i.e. with the right alignment and spacing)? 
I know that using `:\Leftrightarrow` or `:\Longleftrightarrow` gets me the symbol I'm looking for (more or less), but the spacing doesn't look right to me. Constructions using `\iff` or `\colon` didn't really seem to do the trick, either.

Do I have to define such a symbol myself (if so: how?), or is there a package proving this? Unfortunately, I did not find anything myself (especially because I don't know what to search for exactly; I got the description "defined to be logically equivalent" from Wikipedia, since I didn't even know the correct name).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Package `colonequals` provides a vertically centered colon: `\ratio`. Both `\ratio` and `\Leftrightarrow` are of kind `\mathrel`, therefore TeX will not put additional space between them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colonequals}
\newcommand*{\logeq}{\ratio\Leftrightarrow}

\begin{document}
\[ A \logeq B \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

When additional space is wanted between the colon and the arrow (see Raphaels's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198346/symbol-for-defined-to-be-logically-equivalent-%E2%87%94/198353?noredirect=1#comment641594_198353)), then `\colonsep` can be defined and set between the symbols, e.g.:

```
\renewcommand*{\colonsep}{\mkern1mu\relax}% small extra space
\newcommand*{\logeq}{%
  \mathrel{\ratio\colonsep\Leftrightarrow}%
}
```

---

<sub>P.S.
It does not matter here, whether the star form of `\newcommand` is used or not, because there aren't any argument and the definition is not empty. Therefore it is mostly a matter of taste here.</sub>

<sub>I prefer the star form, because I am thinking rather in terms of lower level commands. `\newcommand*` uses `\def`, whereas `\newcommand` uses `\long\def`. Without arguments I do not see a reason for `\long`, therefore I am using `\newcommand*`.</sub>

Comment: Just a quick question: In contrast to the other two answers (which pretty much yield the same results, I think), you used the starred version of `\newcommand`. Is there a good reason to do this? I thought this only makes a difference if you define a command that takes arguments. BTW: I chose your solution (but with `\providecommand` and without `*` (for now), because I like to use packages whenever possible, as I think package authors are generally more clever than I am with those things.

Comment: And with that I mean the use of `\ratio` rather than `\mathrel{\vcentcolon ...` or `\mathrel{\raisebox ...`, not that I think the other two solutions or posters are less clever than you. :D

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have removed the comment with the typo, because editing is no longer possible. It's added to the anwser, following your request. (But in a smaller font, because it is rather unrelated to the original question.)

Comment: Based on the documentation of `colonequals`, is should probably be `\ratio\colonsep\Leftrightarrow`. Also, is should probably be surrounded by `\mathrel`?

Comment: @Raphael A surrounding `\mathrel` is usually not needed, because relational symbols in a row do not have space between them and they behave as one relational symbol regarding the horizontal spacing and a breakpoint is only added after the last symbol. But if space is inbetween, then they should be surrounded by `\mathrel` to avoid breaks at the space.

Comment: Is `\Leftrightarrow` a relational symbol on its own? Anyhow, I just saw that `colonequals` uses `\mathrel` for compound symbols, so I figured it was necessary.

Comment: @Raphael `\Leftrightarrow` is a `\mathrel`, but package `colonequals` adds `\colonsep` or `\colondoublesep`, which are usually not relational symbols and might add break points, thus `\mathrel` is needed there.

Answer (score 13):

The `mathtools` package already has the necessary tool to do that (don't load `amsmath`: mathtools already does it):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\logeq{\mathrel{\vcentcolon\Leftrightarrow}}

\begin{document}

\[ A \logeq A \]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\mathrel` is not needed here, as both symbols are already math relations.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\logeq{\mathrel{\raisebox{.66pt}{:}}\Leftrightarrow}
\begin{document}
\[
A \logeq A
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]