# How to tex $:\iff$ correctly?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, relation-symbols

In the thread [Symbol for "defined to be logically equivalent" (:⇔)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198346/symbol-for-defined-to-be-logically-equivalent-%E2%87%94), we discussed how to tex ":⇔" correctly. As we learnt, the solution is to define the following new command:

```
\newcommand*{\logeq}{\ratio\Leftrightarrow}
```

Now, this only works with

```
\Leftrightarrow
```

I am interested in how to tex the "colon \iff" correctly, that is, with a

```
\Longleftrightarrow
```

instead of a

```
\Leftrightarrow
```

Comment: What does it look like if you just substitute the commands? Does it not look "correct"? If so, why?

Comment: \Longleftrightarrow (or, which is the same, \iff) generates space in front and behind it.

Comment: The spacing isn't that much different when you use `\ratio\Longleftrightarrow` ([picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xgmIf.png)) compared to using `\iff`. Why do you need to use `\iff`?

Comment: @Werner: Thanks, you are right. I thought \Longleftrightarrow would be the same as \iff. But the issue with the spacing only arises with \iff. Your comment is worth an answer. :-)

Comment: `\ratio\Longleftrightarrow` should be good; not `\iff` (that's not really supported in LaTeX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\iff` is similar to `\Longleftrightarrow` but forces an amount of space on either side - a `\;` or `\thickmuskip` (see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)). That,

```
\def\pshow#1{{\let\protect\show#1}}
\pshow\iff
```

yields

```
> \iff =\long macro:
->\;\Longleftrightarrow \;.
\iff ->\protect \iff
```

in the `.log`. In contrast,

```
\pshow\Longleftrightarrow
```

yields

```
> \Longleftrightarrow =\long macro:
->\Leftarrow \joinrel \Rightarrow .
```

in the `.log` - a `\join` or the `rel`ations `\Leftarrow` and `\Rightarrow`, *without* adding spaces around the outside.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colonequals}
\newcommand*{\logeq}{\ratio\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand*{\longeq}{\ratio\Longleftrightarrow}
\begin{document}
\[ A \logeq B \longeq C \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess for those using `\iff` elsewhere it makes sense to use `\newcommand*{\longeq}{\;\ratio\Longleftrightarrow\;}` so that the spacing comes out the same.